# Compute frequency-wavesnumber plot from video

Tags: fourier-analysis

Hey StackExchange Math,

I have a question regarding the computation of a wavenumber-frequency graph from a video. In the paper "Simulating Ocean Water" by Jerry Tessendorf [(link)](http://www-evasion.imag.fr/Membres/Fabrice.Neyret/NaturalScenes/fluids/water/waves/fluids/waves/Jonathan/articlesCG/simulating-ocean-water-01.pdf), it is stated that a wavenumber-frequency graph can be computed from a set of video frames.

I would like to replicate that procedure (i.e. create a program with a video as input and a graph as output), but I am stumped as to how this should be done. In the paper, it is stated that the 3D Fourier Transform should be computed first, after which a 3D Power Spectral Density can be computed from the 3D FT. The desired graph is then a slice of the 3D PSD-volume. Although there are only 3 steps, I do not know how to implement these steps specifically.

My question is, do you know the exact procedure of generating a wavenumber-frequency graph from a video? If this is not the correct place to ask, please refer me. I asked this at StackOverflow, but that platform is more aimed at programming questions, rather than help with general pro